# Absolute positioning and overlapping divs

Tags: html, css

after i include the `position:absolute` in one of my divs, i am noticed that (the div) is being overlap by another div.

[image: screencaps]

here's my fiddle,

the div that I'm talking about is the `#nav-holder` being overlapped by my footer or the black part of the fiddle.

i also used media query in my css.

```
#nav-holder { 
    position: absolute; 
    top: 0; 
    right: 0; 
    width: 200px;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/mjanthrax/pb206Lnz/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please update css

```css
*{box-sizing: border-box}

body, div, h1, h2, h3, h4, h5, h6, p, ul, ol, dl, dt, dd, 
img, form, fieldset, blockquote {
    margin:0 auto;
 padding:0;
}

header, footer, div{
 position: relative; 
 display: block;
}

body {
 background: #222222;
 font: 63% "Century Gothic", Tahoma, Helvetica;
}

#content {
 overflow: hidden;
 background: #eeeeee;
}

#post-wrapper{
 margin: 20px 40px 20px 40px;
 position: relative;
}

#posts {
 background: #fff;
 margin-bottom: 10px;
 padding: 10px;
 overflow: hidden;
}

#nav #list-group a#active {
 background-color: #00aadc;
 border-left-color: #00678b;
 color: #FFF;
}
#nav{
 margin: 0;
 overflow: hidden;
}

#nav #list-group {
 padding: 0;
}

#list-group{
 position: relative;
 display: block;
 padding: 10px 15px;
 margin-bottom: -1px;
 background-color: #fff;
 border: 1px solid #ddd;
}

#nav #list-group a {
 padding: 15px 10px;
 display: block;
 color: #333;
 border-left: solid 5px #FFF;
 text-decoration: none;
 font-size: 1.5em;
}

#nav #list-group a:hover {
      background-color: #e1e1e1;
      border-left-color: #e1e1e1; 
}

#posts h2 {
 font-size: 2.5em; 
 word-wrap: break-word; 
}

#posts h3, #posts h4, h5, h6 {
 padding: 4px 5px;
}

#posts h2, h3, h4, h5, h6 {
 color: #3c3f40;
}

h2#titlename{
 color: #327800;
}

#posts h3 {
 font-size: 1.8em;
}
 
#posts p {
 line-height: 1.3em; 
 font-size: 1.4em; 
}

#posts small {
 font-size: 1.2em;
 padding: 0px 5px;
}
 
#posts a {
 font-size: 1em;
 color: #327800; 
 font-weight: bold; 
 text-decoration: none; 
}
 
#posts blockquote {
 margin: 10px 20px; 
 border-left: 3px solid #cccccc; 
 padding-left: 10px; 
}
hr {
    border: 0;
    height: 1px;
    background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(left, rgba(0,0,0,0), rgba(0,0,0,0.75), rgba(0,0,0,0)); 
    background-image:    -moz-linear-gradient(left, rgba(0,0,0,0), rgba(0,0,0,0.75), rgba(0,0,0,0)); 
    background-image:     -ms-linear-gradient(left, rgba(0,0,0,0), rgba(0,0,0,0.75), rgba(0,0,0,0)); 
    background-image:      -o-linear-gradient(left, rgba(0,0,0,0), rgba(0,0,0,0.75), rgba(0,0,0,0)); 
}

/* MEDIA QUERIES */
@media screen and (min-width: 900px ) {

 #posts{
  margin-right: 220px;
 }
 
 #nav-holder { 
     position: absolute; 
     top: 0; 
     right: 0; 
     width: 200px;
   }
    #post-wrapper{min-height:200px;}

}
```

```html
<div id="content" class="container">
   
   <div id="post-wrapper" >
    <div id="posts">
   <h2>test</h2>
    <small>Posted at 2015-02-28 18:35:04 by <a href="#">jarn</a></small>
    <blockquote><p><h2>test</h2></p></blockquote>
    <p id="linked"><a href="news-admin.php?postid=1">Read More</a></p>
       </div>

    
   <div id="nav-holder">
     <ul id="nav">
     <li id="list-group"><a href="client-information.php">Member Information</a></li>
     <li id="list-group"><a href="#" id="active">Home</a></li>
     <li id="list-group"><a href="client-loan-status.php">Loan Status</a></li>
     <li id="list-group"><a href="client-loan-history.php">Loan History</a></li>
    </ul>
    </div>

  </div><!--end of mainposts-->

 </div><!-- end content -->
```

Or you can  choose [another way](http://jsfiddle.net/pb206Lnz/3/)

Comment: Its all mine pleasure. Cheers

Answer (score 0):

i hope this may help you [Try this demo](http://jsfiddle.net/pb206Lnz/1/)

i just remove the margin 0 auto from the some tags

```
body, div, h1, h2, h3, h4, h5, h6, p, ul, ol, dl, dt, dd, 
img, form, fieldset, blockquote {
margin:0 auto;
padding:0;
}
```

### or

[try second demo](http://jsfiddle.net/pb206Lnz/2/)

Comment: sir, thanks for the answer, but it affects the other divs that im using.

Comment: Its madam who answered :P

Comment: try my second demo link it may help you

Answer (score 0):

try this

```css
*{box-sizing: border-box}


body,h1,h2, h3, h4, h5, h6, p, ul, ol, dl, dt, dd, 
img, form, fieldset, blockquote {
   
    padding:0;
}
div{
    margin:0;
    
}
header, footer, div{
 position: relative; 
 display: block;
}

body {
    margin:0;
 background: #222222;
 font: 63% "Century Gothic", Tahoma, Helvetica;
}

#content {
 overflow: hidden;
 background: #eeeeee;
}

#post-wrapper{
 margin: 20px 40px 20px 40px;
 position: relative;

}

#posts {
 background: #fff;
 margin-bottom: 10px;
 padding: 10px;
 overflow: hidden;
}

#nav #list-group a#active {
 background-color: #00aadc;
 border-left-color: #00678b;
 color: #FFF;
}
#nav{
 margin: 0;
 overflow: hidden;
}

#nav #list-group {
 padding: 0;
}

#list-group{
 position: relative;
 display: block;
 padding: 10px 15px;
 margin-bottom: -1px;
 background-color: #fff;
 border: 1px solid #ddd;
}

#nav #list-group a {
 padding: 15px 10px;
 display: block;
 color: #333;
 border-left: solid 5px #FFF;
 text-decoration: none;
 font-size: 1.5em;
}

#nav #list-group a:hover {
      background-color: #e1e1e1;
      border-left-color: #e1e1e1; 
}

#posts h2 {
 font-size: 2.5em; 
 word-wrap: break-word; 
}

#posts h3, #posts h4, h5, h6 {
 padding: 4px 5px;
}

#posts h2, h3, h4, h5, h6 {
 color: #3c3f40;
}

h2#titlename{
 color: #327800;
}

#posts h3 {
 font-size: 1.8em;
}
 
#posts p {
 line-height: 1.3em; 
 font-size: 1.4em; 
}

#posts small {
 font-size: 1.2em;
 padding: 0px 5px;
}
 
#posts a {
 font-size: 1em;
 color: #327800; 
 font-weight: bold; 
 text-decoration: none; 
}
 
#posts blockquote {
 margin: 10px 20px; 
 border-left: 3px solid #cccccc; 
 padding-left: 10px; 
}
hr {
    border: 0;
    height: 1px;
    background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(left, rgba(0,0,0,0), rgba(0,0,0,0.75), rgba(0,0,0,0)); 
    background-image:    -moz-linear-gradient(left, rgba(0,0,0,0), rgba(0,0,0,0.75), rgba(0,0,0,0)); 
    background-image:     -ms-linear-gradient(left, rgba(0,0,0,0), rgba(0,0,0,0.75), rgba(0,0,0,0)); 
    background-image:      -o-linear-gradient(left, rgba(0,0,0,0), rgba(0,0,0,0.75), rgba(0,0,0,0)); 
}

/* MEDIA QUERIES */
@media screen and (min-width: 900px ) {

 #posts{
  margin-right: 220px;
 }
 
 #nav-holder { 
        position: absolute; 
     top: 0; 
        right: 0; 
       margin:16px;
   }

}
```

```html
<div id="content" class="container">
   
   <div id="post-wrapper" >
    <div id="posts">
   <h2>test</h2>
    <small>Posted at 2015-02-28 18:35:04 by <a href="#">jarn</a></small>
    <blockquote><p><h2>test</h2></p></blockquote>
    <p id="linked"><a href="news-admin.php?postid=1">Read More</a></p>
       </div>

    
   <div id="nav-holder">
     <ul id="nav">
     <li id="list-group"><a href="client-information.php">Member Information</a></li>
     <li id="list-group"><a href="#" id="active">Home</a></li>
     <li id="list-group"><a href="client-loan-status.php">Loan Status</a></li>
     <li id="list-group"><a href="client-loan-history.php">Loan History</a></li>
    </ul>
    </div>

  </div><!--end of mainposts-->

 </div><!-- end content -->
```

I splited

```
body, div, h1, h2, h3, h4, h5, h6, p, ul, ol, dl, dt, dd, 
img, form, fieldset, blockquote {
margin:0 auto;
padding:0;
}
```

in to

```
body,h1,h2, h3, h4, h5, h6, p, ul, ol, dl, dt, dd, 
img, form, fieldset, blockquote {

    padding:0;
}
div{
    margin:0;

}
```